# Change html code in multiple files at one time

Tags: file

Does anyone know if there's an option in Sublime Text 2 (or some other editing program) where I can change content in multiple files at one time?

Let's say I want to change my phone number in the footer on every page, I have to open all files, and copy past it on every single page by myself. I know Wordpress or a local server is a solution, but can it be done without that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the **Sublime Text 2** `Find` > `Find in Files...` menu command.

You can find and replace in multiple documents.

Answer (score 1):

Most editors have that ability. Steps to do this using Notepad++ (free text editor) :

- open the files you want to replace
- Search Menu > Replace
- Enter text to find and then text to replace
- Click [Replace in all open files]

Comment: Thanks, but another comment let's me stay with Sublime Text.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio is certainly one of the programs that can do this. You can find and replace text in all open documents

Edit:

A simple text editor that can do this is textpad. I practically use that for anything.

Comment: Thanks, but another comment here let's me stay with Sublime Text.